# CDH Installation Issues On Centos 7.3

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have created Virtual Machine using Hyper V manager and wanted to install cloudera 5.11 on the VM. 
I followed the steps mentioned in cloudera website.But whenever I check the status of cloudera-scm-server its active in exited state.

Can someone help me out to resolve with this issue ?

[image: Error for Cloudera Services]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: You need to check the log for `cloudera-scm-server` probably in `/var/log/cloudera-scm-server` unless you moved it on install